# Turn Regular Expression into Javascript input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

Ultimately I want a mask that only allows an integer to be entered, or if a decimal/period is entered: allow 0 - 2 digits after the decimal point.

Valid Input

```
1
1.
1.1
1.11
111111111
111111111.
111111111.1
111111111.11
```

Invalid Input

```
a
a.
1.a
1.111
1.1111
```

- string allows any number of digit characters, but only allows 1 decimal/period

  - if a period/decimal exists: only allow 2 digit characters after the decimal

This regular expression does just that:

```
^\d*\.?([\d]){0,2}$
```

Now I need to apply this as a mask to an input.  I am using [Robin Herbots' Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).  I am really struggling making this work.

I am aware that there is the alias `currency`, but that does not work exactly as desired.  What I want is for the input to default to blank on focus/unfocus unless there is input.  `currency` defaults to `0.00`.  I also want to allow the user to delete everything from the field so it will be blank.  `currency` does not allow you to leave the input blank.  Instead it will only allow you to leave the field `0.00`.

```
$('.moneyfield').inputmask("999", {rightAlign: true, numericInput: true});
```

The specific mask should go in the "999" spot.  I could not figure out how to use the built in masks, so that was why I attempted to plug a regular expression into the mask.  So far I have been unsuccessful with both strategies.

Another attempt was to use the `currency` alias and then just override it to what I want it to do.  I wasn't successful with that either.  Here is the definition of the `currency` mask:

```
    currency: {
        prefix: "$ ",
        groupSeparator: ",",
        alias: "numeric",
        placeholder: "0",
        autoGroup: !0,
        digits: 2,
        digitsOptional: !1,
        clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1
    }
```

Comment: a down vote with no explanation?

Comment: You can easily use the `pattern` attribute of inputs in HTML5. It allows you to mask input elements with regular expression exactly like you want. Check out the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: @VivekPradhan great suggestion, unfortunately I need it to work with Safari, and this feature isn't supported in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  You just need to override a couple fields within the `currency` alias:

```
$('.money_field').inputmask({alias: 'currency', rightAlign: true, placeholder: "", prefix: '', autoGroup: false, digitsOptional: true});
```